# Visibility Storyboard works only partial

Tags: wpf, animation, visibility

Please see this `Storyboard`:

```
<Storyboard x:Key="visibilityStoryboardn">
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0:0:0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="0:0:0.0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0" To="1" Duration="0:0:2.0"/>
            <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="0:0:10.0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="1" To="0" Duration="0:0:2.0"/>
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0:0:2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
```

I try to change my element `Visibility` from `Collapsed` to `Visible` with duration of 2 seconds, then wait 10 seconds and change the `Visibility` back to `Collapsed`.

currently this do only the first thing, i mean this change my element to `Visible` with this 2 seconds duration but then start immediately to hide it back to `Collapsed`  but now without and animation style.

Comment: The order in which the Animations take place, is not the order you put them in the xaml code. As pointed in the answer, use BeginTime / KeyTime to arrange your animations on the timeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your only problem is that you defined `BeginTime="0:0:2"` for your `Collapsed` keyframe. It should be `BeginTime="0:0:12"`

```
<ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0:0:0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0">
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
            <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:12.0">
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
            <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
</ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
<DoubleAnimation BeginTime="0:0:0.0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0" To="1" Duration="0:0:2.0"/>
<DoubleAnimation BeginTime="0:0:10.0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="1" To="0" Duration="0:0:2.0"/>
```